# Perl Net::SSH2 and buffering

Tags: perl, ssh

There is a small perl script using Net:SSH2 module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect('testhost') or die $!;
if ($ssh2->auth_publickey('admin', 'id_rsa.pub', 'id_rsa')) {
print "Connected\n";
} else {
print "failed";
}
my $sess = $ssh2->channel() or die "Unable to create chan\n";
$sess->blocking(1);
$sess->shell();
print $sess "sudo /root/remote.pl\n";
print "$_\n" while <$sess>;
$sess->send_eof;
$sess->close;
```

After executing this, sometimes I see output of `/root/remote.pl` and sometimes I don't. I believe that the problem is in output buffering, but I don't how to solve this.

Comment: It is quite hard to use Net::SSH2 properly if possible at all. Go for Net::OpenSSH instead!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the equivalent of `ssh`'s `-t` option

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl has `use_pty`

Comment: Net::SSH2::Channel also has a pty `method`.

Answer (score -1):

If this script is used on a linux system, why not using perl back-tilt to use linux commands instead of using a module?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Command
my $cmd = "ssh login:password@host; sudo /root/remote.pl; exit";

# Execute the command
`$cmd`
```

PS: if the remote.pl script has some print, you should see them.

Comment: Actually i need to execute several commands on remote host, and i'd like to avoid to create ssh connection per each command

Comment: you can actually separate your commands with some ; and then exit.